# How to Prevent users from editing their mysites personal information? (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, permissions, user-profile-property, mysites

I'm trying to prevent users from changing their photo and personal information in mysites.

I go to SharePoint Central Admin > click Manage web applications > click the mysites web app > click User Permissions in ribbon > then Uncheck "Edit Personal User Information".

I click Save and go back to mysites and I can still edit this information. I even recycled the app pool mysites lives in, but no dice.

Is there another way to do this that works?

[image]

[image]

TL;DR?
I was not able to edit user profile properties in IE11, switched to chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things,

- Choggo already mentioned in his response that if their are certain properties then edit that proptery and select Do not Allow...
- 2nd method you just applied, You need to read this

> "If Create Personal Site is checked, users may edit their profile
>   regardless if the Follow People and Edit Profile is checked. So the
>   only way you can turn this off is if you uncheck Create Personal Site
>   as well as Follow People and Edit Profile."

http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/09/sharepoint-2013-preventing-users-from.html

[image]

Comment: I have both unchecked, and I can still edit my mysite personal information. I have given myself admin privileges to User Profile Service Application but I can not edit the user properties. Could be that I'm missing other privileges but not sure where.

Comment: which property you are trying to edit...could you please give us the property name?

Comment: I'd like to restrict all the properties if possible, but for starters I'd like to disable changing their photo. We really prefer that their mysites information that comes from AD remain as it is. 

I'll be happy to provide other information if you need it.
I'm in the farm admin group so I'm supposed to have everything on the box.

Comment: Becuase of Farm admin you are still able to profile information...did you try with a test user after changing th epermissions

Comment: could you please share the screen print where dont allow users to edit....option is disabled....You can also set the Property as Import only...

Comment: See the screen shot in the OP. I have those unchecked for both NT AUTHORITY and ALL Authenticated Users

Comment: did you try with other users who is not administrator? also include screen shot from user profile properties...

Comment: I added the screen shot of Manage User Properties. I did test with a non-administrator.

Comment: You seem to have permissions.I don't mean to offend but, have you hovered the field name to activate the drop down where you choose edit? The fields don't normally show up as links.

Comment: No offence taken, I double checked and when I hover the field names but no drop down is activated. They are just listed out as is in a read only format. I have nothing to allow me to edit really.

Comment: check my updated answer about the drop down, in which browser you are opening the Central admin, try different browser aor may be different PC.

Comment: That's the correct answer. I switched to chrome and it magically worked. In IE 11 it was not working... Imagine that...

Answer (score 3):

Which fields can be edited by a user is configured at the User Profile Service Application

Profile Service Application > Manage User Properties > Select the Property you want to block > Select the Option [image: Disable Access]

Comment: I can't select or change the properties. They are just listed out. Is there something I need to do to make them configurable?

Comment: Depending on the User Property many of the options will be greyed out. The edit Settings should be enabled. If it's not, try adding yourself as an administrator for the User Profile Service Application.

Comment: Okay, I've added myself as an administrator on User Profile Service Application using this reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721057.aspx

unfortunately it doesn't give me a way to edit the properties.